# Plotting maxima within a simplex

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, color, simplex

I am trying to draw a particular maximum plot within a simplex.  I have functions based on two variables:

Write p,q for the two variables where p,q \geq 0 and p + q \leq 1.  This defines the simplex I am interested in. (Think of, say, p on the x-axis and q on the y-axis.)

The functions are then of the following form:

f(p,q) = 22.5p + 10(1-p)

g(p,q) = 40(1-p-q) + 15(p+q)

h(p,q) = 10(1-q) + 22.5q.

(I am giving examples of functions---there are several I want to look at.)

I am interested in which function is "highest" for any given (p,q). So, for any given (p,q) in the simplex, I want to look at the max {f, g, h}.  (The functions are such that almost always the maximum will be unique.) I then want it plot the point (p,q) as, say, red if f is the maximum function, blue if g is the maximum function, and green if h is the maximum function.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done within mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piggybacking on [@kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202557/6358), but using a right triangle rather than equilateral, so we can see `p` and `q` on the axes and to highlight the symmetry between `f` and `h`.

How about:

```
Plot3D[max[p, q], {p, q} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}],
  ColorFunction ->
  (Which[#3 == f[#1, #2], Red, #3 == g[#1, #2], Green, #3 == h[#1, #2], Blue] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A dirty trick to get a 2D plot is to move the `ViewPoint` to `{0, 0, \[Infinity]}`:

```
Plot3D[max[p, q], {p, q} \[Element] 
  Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[#3 == f[#1, #2], Red, #3 == g[#1, #2], 
     Green, #3 == h[#1, #2], Blue] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Axes -> {True, True, False}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's another possible 2D solution:

```
DensityPlot[
  Which[
    max[p, q] == f[p, q], 1,
    max[p, q] == g[p, q], 2,
    max[p, q] == h[p, q], 3
  ],
 {p, q} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[#1 == 1, Red, #1 == 2, Green, #1 == 3, Blue] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

(similar output)

Of course hard coding the number of functions is ugly; it'd be nice to have this accept an arbitrary number of functions to compare!

Comment: These pictures are beautiful.  But I was rather hoping for a 2-Dimensional version of this---with say p on the x-axis and q on the y-axis.  Is there any way to project the 3D figure onto 2D? Or draw it originally as 2D?

Comment: @kglr any ideas on making your solution 2D?

Comment: @ChrisK, found something that works-- could be cleaner.

Comment: @kglr Yeah, too bad `RegionPlot` leaves a big hole in the middle by default.

Comment: @kglr may I ask a follow up on the comments here?  I'm working with a more complicated version of the question I asked earlier. For various reasons, I ended up using the answer below that uses RegionPlot. I've been struggling getting a big white hole in the middle.  I then noticed the comment above on RegionPlot.  Why does this hole arise with RegionPlot and why does the MWE below not suffer from that problem?  (I must have changed the solution below in a way that inserted the hole.)

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]

f[p_, q_] := 22.5 p + 10 (1 - p)
g[p_, q_] := 40 (1 - p - q) + 15 (p + q)
h[p_, q_] := 10 (1 - q) + 22.5 q

max[p_, q_] := Max[f[p, q], g[p, q], h[p, q]]


Plot3D[max[p, q], {p, q} ∈ SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1], 
  Filling -> Bottom, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

```
{rf, rg, rh} =  Quiet @
  Reduce[#[p, q] >= max[p, q] , {p, q} ∈ SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]] & /@ {f, g, h};

RegionPlot[{rf, rg, rh}, {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask for help in understanding the code for future issues? I think rf defines the region of (p,q) where f is the maximum, etc.  This is achieved with '{rf, rg, rh} =  Quiet @
  Reduce[#[p, q] >= max[p, q] , {p, q} ∈ SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]] & /@ {f, g, h};' Can you please explain this line... I'm confused by the role of  'Quiet @
  Reduce[#[p, q] >= max[p, q]' and  '& /@ {f, g, h}' @kglr (I hope this is the right formatting for comments?)

Comment: @Amanda, you are about `rf` (`rg` and `rh`). I used `Quiet` to suppress warning messages that `Reduce` gives (try it by removing `Quiet @ ` to see what i mean). For the second part  related to `&` , `/@` .., see (1) [`Function (&)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and (2) [`Map (/@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) in the documentation center ...

Comment: ... The function `Reduce[#[p, q] >= max[p, q] , {p, q} ∈ SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]] &` a _pure function_ (a function with unnamed argument(s))) (where [`Slot (#)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) is a placeholder for the argument.)  We could have defined the same function using `myreduce[arg_]:=Reduce[arg[p, q] >= max[p, q] , {p, q} ∈ SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]]`.  When supplied an argument (`myreduce[func]` for example) this function gives the result of `Reduce[func[p, q] >= max[p, q] , {p, q} ∈ SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]]`.